# boto3 - getting a listing of users in each group

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Using boto3

I have many groups, just over 75 of them. I would like to find the users and the in each group and the last time their password was used. (the 'PasswordLastUsed' key - I am not sure if I can use it with get_group. I see it in the docs but it does not work.

```
response = iam.get_group(

GroupName='groupA'
#GroupName=['groupA','groupB','groupC']
)
print(response['Group']['GroupName'])
for user in response['Users']:
    print("UserName: {0}\nArn: {1}\n"
    .format(user['UserName'], user['Arn']))
```

I would like to know how i can iterate through each group so it looks like this:

(the above code will do for 1 group and look like below, I just would like to do >1 group at a time.

```
groupA
UserName: mickey
Arn:   hkhjjklljlj
UserName: donald
Arn:   hkhjjklljlj
groupB:
UserName: goofy
Arn:   hkhjjfgkgfk
UserName: daffy
Arn:   lkjkljkoj
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use [list_groups](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_groups) to get all groups, and then you can query for details of each group:

```
response = iam.list_groups()
for group in response['Groups']:    
    group_details = iam.get_group(GroupName=group['GroupName'])
    print(group['GroupName'])
    for user in group_details['Users']:
        print(" - ", user['UserName'])
```

Comment: that works perfect --- any way to exclude a group or two easily?